# Adding Mouse Drag listeners over a check Box

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, mouselistener

I need to do something every time the user tries to drag a CheckBox and paste it from one panel to another.
I know Java offers drag and drop API but I don't exactly want the check box to be dragged from one panel to another. 
What I want is to give the user an illusion of drag and drop and behind the scenes I want my code running and performing certain operations. How should I do that ??

[image]

Now when I drag and drop the check Box image1 from panelleft to panel_right I want certain code to run in the background on that drag and drop action of the user

```
for(ResourceListObject currentImage : imageList ){


        imageOnRepositoryCheckBox[checkBoxNumber] = new JCheckBox(currentImage.getName());
        imageOnRepositoryCheckBox[checkBoxNumber].setBounds(6, gapping+checkBoxNumber*26, 368, 23);
        imageOnRepositoryCheckBox[checkBoxNumber].setTransferHandler(new FromTransferHandler());
        if(imagesToBeImported != null){
            if(imagesToBeImported.contains(currentImage)){

                imageOnRepositoryCheckBox[checkBoxNumber].setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                imageOnRepositoryCheckBox[checkBoxNumber].setToolTipText("This image is already on the list of images to be imported and can't be selected again.");

            }
        }
            panel.add(imageOnRepositoryCheckBox[checkBoxNumber]);
            checkBoxNumber++;

    }
```

and the second piece of code that would run is

```
 for(JCheckBox currentCheckBox : imageOnRepositoryCheckBox){
                if(currentCheckBox.isSelected()){
                    Iterator itr = imagesOfCurrentRepository.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()) {
                        ResourceListObject iteratedImage = (ResourceListObject)itr.next();
                        if(iteratedImage.getName().equals(currentCheckBox.getText())){

                           boolean isAdded = imagesToBeImported.add(iteratedImage);
                           descriptionPanel.updateDescription("The image selected for importing is "+currentCheckBox.getText());

                           if(isAdded){
                               currentCheckBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                               currentCheckBox.setToolTipText("This image is already on the list of images to be imported and can't be selected again.");
                           }
                        }

                    }

                    updateImagesToBeImportedPanel(panel_1, imagesToBeImported);
                }
                checkBoxNumber++;
             }
```

So I want the user to think of it as drag and drop but in the backend I would be doing my own thing .

Comment: Maybe you can perform the drag normally and then when it's dropped make sure that the initial state is restored/unchanged. Anyway this is too vague, make a simple runnable code with some test and share your problems with it.

Comment: You mean to say that I have to use Drag and Drop API and in the method in which we write what happens when the Drop operation is performed, I put in my code , whaetever I want to do ??
Ok I would post that in a few minutes.

Comment: Yes, but It's just a random though. Try implementing a simple drag and drop application with your own customizable code, and post any problems you have to move from this approach to your goal.

Comment: You could fake it with a glasspane that paints the checkbox while it's being dragged and then hide the glasspane.  But, I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish or why you want the user to drag a check box.  Seems to me there's a better way.